# Create an actual table with SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, macos, swiftui

I'm an absolute Swift-Newbie and I want to create an actual table with 2 dimensions. I made some vertical lists, but when I put them in a HStack, the text-boxes in them doesn't really line up. What do I have to do or is this the wrong approach?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure how you want it to look like, but simple solutions can go into the same direction you already pointed at:

```
struct ExampleRow: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Example Row")
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {

        ZStack {
            HStack {
                List {
                    Section(header: Text("Column A")) {
                        ExampleRow()
                        ExampleRow()
                        ExampleRow()
                    }
                }.listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
                    .disabled(true)

                List {
                    Section(header: Text("Column B")) {
                        ExampleRow()
                        ExampleRow()
                        ExampleRow()
                    }
                }.listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
                    .disabled(true)
            }
            Rectangle().fill(Color.gray).opacity(0.4).frame(width: CGFloat(1))
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Picture]

Comment: I have not tried yet, but won't the rows misalign if the text in one cell in one column is so long that it wraps and the row height lengthens?